# Create named Versions of Google Sheets (or other documents) automatically on a schedule

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create named versions of a file on a schedule, say once per week.  Refer [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/named-versions-new-version-history-google-docs) for an example.  The named version should be something like the file name + date so that it can be searchable.

I feel like this should be possible with something like Google's App script, but I'm not sure how to access the "name version" feature.  Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to handle named versions of Google Spreadsheets by using Google Apps Script and Google Drive API as they haven't methods to do this.

This could be possible by using a tool that simulate the user actions like opening a spreadsheet by using a web browser and doing the click and type actions. Please ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) for a tool like this.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script
- https://developers.google.com/drive